# Setting CertificatePolicy=$TrustAll using C#

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, cryptography, x509certificate

I currently use this code in power shell:

```
$TrustAll=$TAAssembly.CreateInstance("Local.ToolkitExtensions.Net.CertificatePolicy.TrustAll")
    [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::CertificatePolicy=$TrustAll
```

How can I do this in C#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a sample that will trust every certificate.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

public class Program : ICertificatePolicy {

    public bool CheckValidationResult (ServicePoint sp, 
        X509Certificate certificate, WebRequest request, int error)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public static void Main (string[] args) 
    {
        ServicePointManager.CertificatePolicy = new Program ();
        WebRequest wr = WebRequest.Create (args [0]);
        Stream stream = wr.GetResponse ().GetResponseStream ();
        Console.WriteLine (new StreamReader (stream).ReadToEnd ());
    }
}
```

If you want to know more on the subject (e.g. alternatives) I suggest you to read the Mono's wiki [article](http://www.mono-project.com/UsingTrustedRootsRespectfully) on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help:

```
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = {$true}
```

Comment: Looks like he's wanting the c# version but this helps me! This turns the 29 line Ignore-SslErrors function in [this script](http://poshcode.org/2318) into 1. Sweet :-)